# error: Class has not been declared despite header inclusion, and the code compiling fine elsewhere

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header

So I have a class included in another class that keeps throwing a compile error of the form "error: 'ProblemClass' has not been declared. The files are set up thusly:

```
#ifndef PROBLEMCLASS_H
#define PROBLEMCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class ProblemClass
{
  public:

    virtual void Init() = 0;
};

#endif
```

and the class where the error occurs looks like this:

```
#ifndef ACLASS_H
#define ACLASS_H

#include "problemclass.h"

class AClass : public Base
{
  public:

    void DoSomething(ProblemClass* problem);

};

#endif
```

The compile error occurs at void Dosomething();

I'm aware the code here isn't enough to solve the problem. I've been unable to create a minimal example that can reproduce it. So my question is much more general; what sort of things might cause this? Is there anything in particular I should look for, or some line of enquiry I should be following to track it down?

This code compiles fine in an almost identical version of the project.

Help of any sort would be greatly appreciated, no matter how vague. I'm using codeblocks 10.05 with mingw4.4.1 in win 7 64 bit.

Comment: Check your spelling, 9 out of 10 these errors come because you spelled one of the identifiers wrong.

Comment: I've been over that with a fine tooth comb, and had a friend look over it too, so I think spelling is unlikely to be the problem. As well as the fact that it compiles fine in a slightly different version of the project where both classes exist and have the same relationship.

Comment: looks ok to me. Have you implemented a body for DoSomething?

Comment: Can you give the complete code, especially the difference between the broken one and the "almost identical version"?

Comment: The body for dosomething has been implemented yep. A complete functional code would be fairly large. Is there any particular way I should post it other than in code tags?

Comment: Is it possible that some other macro defines `PROBLEMCLASS_H` in the code that causes the error?

Comment: The program compiles after I moved some includes out of base and into AClass. I'm still unsure as to what happened, but thanks to all for their time.

Comment: Does `problemclass.h` include `aclass.h` (directly or indirectly)? That would cause this problem, and can be fixed by replacing one or both `#include`s with forward declarations of the class(es).

Comment: "The program compiles after I moved some includes out of base and into AClass" -- Sounds like you had a cyclic dependency. Somehow one of the includes of `ProblemClass` included `AClass` and when `AClass` includes `ProblemClass` again the compiler ignores that include statement to prevent infinite recursion.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You seem to be saying that the code you are showing doesn't actually produce the compiler error that you are having a problem with. So we can only guess. Here are some possibilities:

- You could have forgot to include `problemclass.h` from the file where you are using `ProblemClass`.
- You could have misspelled the name of `ProblemClass` either in its own header file or in the place where you are using it. This can be hard to spot if it is a capitalization error such as writing `Problemclass` or `problemClass` instead of `ProblemClass`.
- You could have copy-pasted your inclusion guard `#defines` from one header file to another and then forgot to change the defined names. Then only the first of those two included header files would take effect.
- You could have placed `ProblemClass` in a namespace `A`, in which case you must refer to `ProblemClass` as `A::ProblemClass` if you are referring to it from outside the namespace `A`.
- You may be using templates and not expecting two-phase lookup to work the way [it does](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup).
- You could have misspelled the file name in your include. The compiler would not report an error on that if you also have an old version of that file under the misspelled name.
- You could have made `ProblemClass` a macro that only gets defined after you include `problemclass.h`, in which case what you see as `ProblemClass` gets replaced by something else by the macro preprocessor.
- You could have defined `ProblemClass` in a header file other than `problemclass.h` and then `problemclass.h` actually defines something else.

Comment: This is a good list. However, I had this problem and it was that I had specified an #include in the for AClass in ProblemClass.h too. So, when it was compiling ProblemClass.cc, it would include both headers before it could process the ProblemClass.h header. Thought I'd add that to the list.

Comment: @Homer6 this happens to me sometimes, too. Especially when I develop some new code modules in an independent project and try to include it into the main-project later on. Often there is need for some refactoring, and I just miss to delete those "helper-includes" I used in the independent part, which will cause exactly that problem.

Comment: One should add:
One could have ``#included`` a file in a namespace ``A`` decleration  in a header file (what is absolutely stupid and unintended), (so we injected code into the namespace ``A``) and in the translation unit this code needs to be refered to as A::gaga(), so the compiler complaines of not finding the function ``gaga()`` !!!

Comment: +1 for bullet point three. I refactored a class into parent and child and kept the original #ifndef <CLASS> #define in both, so the compiler complained about everything in the now parent class being missing. Thank you!

Comment: Ran into this issue when I created a class that had the same name another class had when it was created. It was later renamed, but the header guards were identical because they are auto-generated and I never think to change them when I rename the file.

Comment: #include order matters! I had some class defined in A.h and referred to it in B.h. Then I included B.h before A.h in some cpp file. It complained class was not defined. Switching the two includes solved the problem.

Comment: - you could have `#ifdef SOMETHING` in the header file that prevents the definition from execution

Answer (score 53):

I've had that same error message as a result of a **circular dependency** in my header files / classes:

foo.hpp:

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.hpp" // <-- here

class Foo {
public:
    int value = 0;

    void do_foo(Bar myBar) {
        printf("foo + %d\n", myBar.value);
    }
};

#endif //FOO_HPP
```

bar.hpp:

```
#ifndef BAR_HPP
#define BAR_HPP

#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.hpp" // <-- and here

class Bar {
public: 
    int value = 1;      

    void do_bar(Foo myFoo) {
        printf("bar = %d \n", myFoo.value);
    }
};

#endif //BAR_HPP
```

Compiling with: `g++ -std=c++11 foo.hpp -o foo` resulted in the following output:

```
In file included from foo.hpp:5:0:
bar.hpp:11:15: error: ‘Foo’ has not been declared
bar.hpp: In member function ‘void Bar::do_bar(int)’:
bar.hpp:12:32: error: request for member ‘value’ in ‘myFoo’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

Comment: solutions to circular dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Answer (score 2):

Please post the command you are using for compilation.  I've seen this issue if you have 2 separate files that include the same header and you are doing a gcc *.cpp.  This happens because the #define gets defined for the entire gcc instance and not just for each individual object file being compiled.

Ex.

File1

```
#ifndef FILE1_HPP
#define FILE1_HPP 1
....
#endif
```

Then two separate files that reference it.

```
#include <file1.hpp>
```

Trying to compile all at the same time will cause one of the cpp files to fail since FILE1_HPP was already defined (causing the header file to be ignored for that cpp file).

```
gcc -Wall *.cpp
```

Answer is either remove the #ifndef, or to compile each file into its own object files and then link them into your main application.

Comment: `#define` absolutely should not affect other compilation units (unless also reached in the other unit).  If you can repro this, it would be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone seeing this post and having this error, I want to point out that this frequently happens to me when I forget to add the class specifier before a function name, wherein that class function uses something privately defined in the class's header.

EG:

Header

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void SomeFunc();
private:
    typedef int SomeType_t;
};
```

Source (Will throw error *SomeType_t is not defined*)

```
void SomeFunc()
{
    SomeType_t dummy = 0;
}
```

Source (Fixed)

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunc()
{
    SomeType_t dummy = 0;
}
```

This is a dumb, but really easy mistake to make and not see until after you have given yourself three concussions from hitting your head against the desk.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could think of that would cause the compile error based on what you have presented is if `PROBLEMCLASS_H` somehow got redefined outside the header file. Like for example:

```
//main.cpp
#define PROBLEMCLASS_H
#include "aclass.h"

int main() {}
```

One idea you can try is to not include 'problemclass.h' in 'aclass.h' but just do a forward declare of `ProblemClass` instead. For this to work you have to make sure `AClass`'s definition only contains references or pointers to `ProblemClass` -- you don't want the compiler to try and take the size of `ProblemClass` which would need its full definition.

```
//aclass.h
#ifndef ACLASS_H
#define ACLASS_H

class ProblemClass;

class AClass : public Base
{
  public:
    void DoSomething(ProblemClass* problem);
};

#endif
```

Another technique you can use to help track down this header problem is to just preprocess the problematic '.cpp' compilation unit. Open up the preprocessed output file(usually '.i' extension) and inspect what is actually happening. This is handy especially if the 'includes' are numerous and hard to predict.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar problem and it took me a while to find out why.

In your case, you may define PROBLEMCLASS_H in some other header files. 
The consequence is your cpp file will skip the definition in the header file. In other words, the line `#include "problemclass.h"` is skipped.

In my case, I am using MingW64 under Linux. Say I have a header file IO.h:

```
// IO.h
#ifndef _IO_H_
#define _IO_H_

class A{
...
};
#endif
```

In my main.cpp file:

```
// main.cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include "IO.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 //...
}
```

The cpp file looks innocent. However, when `unistd.h` is included, it secretly includes `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/io.h` supplied by MingW, and this `io.h` looks like:

```
// io.h
#ifndef _IO_H_
#define _IO_H_
...
#endif /* End _IO_H_ */
```

Now you can see that inclusion of `unistd.h` will lead to the inclusion `io.h` from MingW, and that will hide my own IO.h. I guess that's a similar problem like yours.

If you switch the order of includes (put `#include <unistd.h>` after IO.h), the program compiles. But this is not a good suggestion. I recommend that you don't use _IO_H_ to guard your own IO.h.

To understand how/why your `PROBLEMCLASS_H` is included, I agree with @greatwolf, you can use `g++ -E` to output the preprocessor output and manually examine it. Check what files are included before your `PROBLEMCLASS_H` and in what order they are included. I hope that can help solve your problem.

Comment: this is my case. typo in header file ifndef as ifdef, so the header file will never be included..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've discovered what I was doing wrong: following your example, I've included ProblemClass in AClass, thus causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare 'ProblemClass' should do the thing. Forward declarations are necessary to resolve circular includes that throw off linker/compiler errors.
If I have that kind of problems, a go through headers and make Forward Declaration whenever possible, which anyway is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,
A.h is included in B1.h and B2.h
B2.h is also included in B2.cpp

Used
#Pragma once
in class A.h
this resolved the issue.