# Is it possible to access a derived object from another derived object both using the same base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, compiler-errors

I have an abstract base `Object` class and two derived classes from it: `Paddle` and `Ball`. `Paddle`'s constructor accepts as a parameter a pointer to `Ball` so that i can get its position to calculate the paddle movement:

```
Paddle::Paddle(Vec location, Vec size, float AIspeed, Ball* prtBall)
    :  Object(location, size)
{
    /* ... */
    gameBall = ptrBall;
}
```

IntelliSense does not flag this as invalid, but whenever I compile the code, VS2013 unexpectedly throws the following errors:

```
1>\object\paddle.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Ball'
1>\object\paddle.h(43): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>\object\paddle.h(43): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>\object\paddle.h(18): error C2065: 'gameBall' : undeclared identifier
1>\object\paddle.h(18): error C2065: 'ptrBall' : undeclared identifier
1>\object\paddle.h(30): error C2065: 'gameBall' : undeclared identifier
```

The first two are particularly interesting... From the looks of it, the compiler is not recognizing that `Ball*` is a type. Line 8 is the one above and these are lines 40-44:

```
private:
    void Foo();

    Ball* gameBall;
    float bar;
```

At first I was thinking that I forgot to include `Ball`'s definition in the file `paddle.h`. But this is not the case. Is what I`m doing correct or is there a flaw currently overlooked?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Sure @JoachimPileborg working on it right now :)

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize the symbol `Ball`.  Did you forget to #include the .h file where `Ball` is defined in `paddle.h`?

Comment: Does `ball.h` also `#define <paddle.h>`?  Circular includes cause problems, even with include guards.  Perhaps you need to use a forward-declaration instead of an include.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14909997/103167 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6554492/103167

Comment: Indeed, it was a circular include @BenVoigt Paddle.h was not including directly Ball.h, but they were mutually included upper on my #include stack, noticed that when working on a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided the access rights to the sibling's data member or method is public.

Siblings don't have access to other sibling's private or protected data methods and data members.

You could create a virtual method in the Parent class.  One sibling can then go through the parent (via the function) to get the data; but then as I have learned, life is better when you talk to your sibling directly rather than going through the parent. :-)