# c++ get instance of parent from child

Tags: c++, events, inheritance, callback, parent

Hey am creating a game as a school project in c++, and trying to get an instance of the parent class from the child class. I have created a class CollisionHandler witch works as a callback or event listener sort of. This worked until recently but after some changes in my code I can't get it to work again.... What is the proper way to do this ?

```
class CollisionHandler{
public:
    explicit CollisionHandler(){};
    ~CollisionHandler(){};
    virtual Collision checkWorldCollision(sf::FloatRect playerPos);
    virtual Collision checkPlayerCollision(sf::FloatRect attackPos);
};
```

Class implementing CollisionHandler:

```
class Game : public CollisionHandler{
public:

    Game();
    ~Game();

    enum GameType{
        TYPE_LOCAL,
        TYPE_LAN
    };

    enum GameState{
        PLAYING,
        PAUSED,
        ENDED
    };

    void initialize(int width, int height, Map map, GameType type);
    void addPlayer(PlayerInfo& playerInfo, PlayerControls playerControls);
    RunState start(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    RunState resume(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    void pause();
    void exit();

    Collision checkWorldCollision(sf::FloatRect playerPos);
    Collision checkPlayerCollision(sf::FloatRect attackPos);

private:
    RunState run(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    GameState _currState;
    World _world;
    GameType _gameType;
    std::vector<Player> _players;
    int playerAmount;
};
```

Then am initializing a class Player that uses Game as CallbackHandler:

```
player.initialize(info, &game);
```

everything worked fine until recently, but nothing should have affected this part of the code. Getting this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Player::initialize(PlayerInfo&, Game*)’
 player.initialize(info, &game);
```

Also getting this error:

```
error: ‘CollisionHandler’ has not been declared
 void setCollisionHandler(CollisionHandler* collisionHandler);
```

Sorry for all the back and forth, but i have narrowed it down to be a declaration error even though everything is included:

Comment: So figured it was a bit unclear, but my main question is, how to deal with inheritance and instanciation in c++ ?

Comment: It is a compilation error in the `Player` class that is not in your post. The signatures just do not match between the caller and the callee.

Comment: If i replace Game class with just and Instance of CollisionHandler, everything works fine, but can post more of my code if that would help :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration errors, don't know what happened but found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554492/error-class-has-not-been-declared-despite-header-inclusion-and-the-code-compil)

and created a new file and instance of CollisionHandler, everything is working again. Thanks