# 'WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS' not defined in wtsapi32.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I included wtsapi32 header file in c++ code in windows (using Mingw).

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
#include "wtsapi32.h"
```

I am getting an error says,

> c:\mingw\include\wtsapi32.h:200:3: error: **'WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS' has not been declared**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Class has not been declared despite header inclusion, and the code compiling fine elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554492/error-class-has-not-been-declared-despite-header-inclusion-and-the-code-compil)

Comment: here the error comes in windows default header files, data type is not defined @Adelin

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR I am using `Windows 10`. Is that any problem?

Comment: how interesting used operation system can affect compiler errors ? `_WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP` faster error in this because [`_WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-_wts_virtual_class) define from Vista. also you use not standard headers files, but from *mingw*. possible it wrong/incomplete

Comment: @RbMm I was trying to get access token from `WTSQueryUserToken` method. Can you give me some reference to use this?

Comment: but your question about compiler error(s)

Answer (score 1):

@RbMm is likely right - this is probably a mingw thing.  Anyway, this definition is not going to change so you can just declare the enum in your own code, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-_wts_virtual_class) (thank you for the link, @RbMm):

```
typedef enum _WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS {
  WTSVirtualClientData  ,
  WTSVirtualFileHandle
} WTS_VIRTUAL_CLASS;
```